# Aggregate Equivalent of Spark in Flink

Tags: scala, aggregate, apache-flink

Is there any equivalent of Spark's [RDD Aggregate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) for Flink's [DataSet](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet)?

After a few hours of searching it seems there is nothing.

Flink's DataSet API has an `aggregate(agg: Aggregations, field: String): AggregateDataSet[T]` but from its documentaion it seems its not similar to Spark.

Do I have to implement a custom [Aggregations](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/aggregation/Aggregations.java)?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly the same as Spark's but did you take a look at [reduce](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-scala/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/api/scala/DataSet.scala#L622)?

Comment: But `aggregate` does more than `reduce`, isn't? If I understand well, `reduce` is a specific type of aggregation.

Comment: Well you're right in saying that the signature is not the same but I guess you should be able to do everything with one or the other. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Start with an initial element, apply an opperation and then reduce it.